# find $y$ in terms of $x$ if $dy/dx = x^4/y^3$ and $y(0) = 2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the following problem:

*"find y in terms of x if $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = x^4/y^3$ and y(0) = 2, submit the answer y(x) = ..."*

What I understand the question to be is: "find the particular solution to the given differential equation that passes through the points (0,2)" - However in my attempt to answer it, I see that I was incorrect.

### Is it possible that the question is asking for something else? and if so, could you help me understand what the question is indeed asking for?

note: I have included links below to photos of my work, in case that is easier to read than my web formatting.

1. I begin by separating the equation

$$y^3\, \mathrm dy = x^4 \,\mathrm dx$$

2. I integrate both sides

$$y^4/4  = x^5/5 + C$$

3. I isolate for y

$$y^4 = \frac45  x^5 + C$$

$$y = (4/5)^{1/4}  x^{5/4} + C$$

4. Plugging in the coordinates from the IC, I get C = 2

$y = (4/5)^{1/4} x^{5/4} + 2$ , and this is the solution I think the question is asking for.

---

Lastly there is a second part to the problem, where they ask for the interval of definition.

Based on the solution I obtained, I would think the the solution would be defined for all values of x greater than or equal to 0.

*However* my answer can only be submitted in the form [] < x < [] , in which the lower bound is greater than, and not greater than or equal to.

This leads me to question my understanding of what they are asking for.

In case my formatting is unclear,  I am open to suggestions on how to make my post more user friendly for the reader. As well, I have included a link to a [photo of my work](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbcq89fwi7n3wt8/diff%20eq%20problem%20WWA2P4.pdf?dl=0), in case that is easier for you to read. As well as the [original question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmtt4z29xt3nuv5/diff%20eq%20problem%20WWA2P4%20OP.png?dl=0)

I should stipulate that this is part of a homework assignment for marks, and therefor please do not explicitly answer the question they are asking for, rather please guide me in finding my error.

Thank you all.

Comment: $y^2=a^2$ has 2 solutions $y=\pm a$, that being said this might not be the only "flaw" or if it is a "flaw".

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that
$$
y^4=A+C
$$
has the solution
$$
y\ne\sqrt[4]{A}+C,
$$
it should be
$$
y=\sqrt[4]{A+C},
$$

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you. I will be more careful.